# Dynamic php page with database id

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to create a dynamic php page, that changes with the id of the database row.

But till now I got this, but it doesn't show anything :-(
Have tried to find some answers from previous questions, but found nothing that helped my problem.

Anybody got any nice and simple tips how to do this??

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = '$term' LIMIT 1;";
        $q = $mysqli->query($q);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
            echo    "<div class=\"article\">".
                "<div class=\"title\">".$result['title']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"body\">".$result['description']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"desc\">"."Kort beskrivelse: ".$result['description']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"ingredients\">"."ingredienser: ".$result['ingredients']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"amount\">"."amount: ".$result['amount']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"guidance\">"."guidance: ".$result['guidance']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"hour\">"."hour: ".$result['hour']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"minutes\">"."minutes: ".$result['minutes']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"laktose\">"."laktose: ".$result['laktose']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"okologisk\">"."okologisk: ".$result['okologisk']."</div>".
            "</div>";
        }
        else {
            /* Article not found */
        }
    }
?>
```

Would love to learn another way to do this, if there are any more simple ones.

- I only included the php code, and not my database connection. It works, I have tested it :-)

Comment: you try change one of '$q' to another name and see what the result. and try this
$q = "SELECT * FROM opskriftreg WHERE id = '$term' LIMIT 1";

Comment: Turn on error reporting for a start... You don't seem to understand the language very well.

Comment: You are using `$term`, but it doesn't seem to be defined in this context.

Comment: `$_GET['id']` != `$_POST['id']`, `$id` != `$term`, you are mixing OOP and procedural methods, if you `echo "SELECT * FROM \`opskriftreg\` WHERE \`id\` = '$term' LIMIT 1;"';` are you seeing what you would expect

Comment: Ups I uploaded my old one with tables. And what did you mean about me not understanding the language? I have error report on, and it shows nothing

Comment: Adding to what @SteveRobbins said: You should turn on error reporting with `E_NOTICE` and/or `E_STRICT`. This way you would have caught the use of the uninitialized variable `$term`. See [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have complete mess with variables

Condition use `$_GET['id']`

after that you arr using `$id = .... $_POST['id']`

and inside SQL you have `id = '$term'`

Try to be consistent in using variables. I can assume that you need to update your code to

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

     $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1"); 
     $statement->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']); //Replace ? above with our input, specifying ‘i’ meaning that we are passing one integer.
     $statement->execute(); //Run the query
     $result = $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

     // here goes your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$q = "SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = '$term' LIMIT 1;";
```

So I suppose your query simply returns zero rows since you are discarding `$_POST['id']` and possibly searching <del>by a literal `'$term'` string</del> an empty string.

```
echo "SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = '$term' LIMIT 1;";
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: term in D:\tmp\test.php on line 3
>   SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = '' LIMIT 1;

To make it worse, you only run the query if a third variable exists:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1;";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while ($result = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
        echo    "<div class=\"article\">".
            "<div class=\"title\">".$result['title']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"body\">".$result['description']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"desc\">"."Kort beskrivelse: ".$result['description']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"ingredients\">"."ingredienser: ".$result['ingredients']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"amount\">"."amount: ".$result['amount']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"guidance\">"."guidance: ".$result['guidance']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"hour\">"."hour: ".$result['hour']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"minutes\">"."minutes: ".$result['minutes']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"laktose\">"."laktose: ".$result['laktose']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"okologisk\">"."okologisk: ".$result['okologisk']."</div>".
        "</div>";
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Article not found */
    }
}
?>
```

I've assumed you want to use the `$_GET` variable instead of `$term` or `$_POST`.

Comment: I get an error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/www/.dk/work/dynamic_page.php on line 14

`$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);`

Comment: You need to change the $connection variable to your MYSQLi connection variable

Comment: Back to square one :P Now it shows nothing again at dynamic_page.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, and I prefer PDO to mysqli, but it should get you closer.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false);
if ($id) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `opskriftreg` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        echo    "<div class=\"article\">".
            "<div class=\"title\">".$result['title']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"body\">".$result['description']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"desc\">"."Kort beskrivelse: ".$result['description']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"ingredients\">"."ingredienser: ".$result['ingredients']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"amount\">"."amount: ".$result['amount']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"guidance\">"."guidance: ".$result['guidance']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"hour\">"."hour: ".$result['hour']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"minutes\">"."minutes: ".$result['minutes']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"laktose\">"."laktose: ".$result['laktose']."</div>".
            "<div class=\"okologisk\">"."okologisk: ".$result['okologisk']."</div>".
        "</div>";
    }
    else {
        /* Article not found */
    }
}
```